# Can I recover my Skype phone call records from 3-4 years ago?

Tags: history, phone

Is there a way I can get my Skype phone call records (history) from 2013? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a copy of the `main.db` file, then you can see the old chat history.

> 1. Hold down the Windows key on your keyboard, then press R to bring up the Run window. ...
> 2. Type `%appdata%\Skype` into the Run window and press Enter.
> 3. Open the folder named after your Skype Name.
> 4. Find the `main.db` file in the folder, this file is your chat history.

---

Other thing you can download this free application – [SkypeLogView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/skype_log_view.html)

With `SkypeLogView` you can open `main.db` file and see which chat and call data are available there.

Comment: This answer assumes you have the same computer and have never formatted it or upgraded it.